# Can a method inside a spring controller validate an abstract parameter type?

Tags: java, spring, controller, attributes, abstract

I am working on an application that allows users to create 5 different types of orders.  I am using hibernate and all 5 subclasses extend the Order class which is abstract.  What i would like to be able to do is to have ONE JSP to create all 5 types of orders and pass whatever subclass type the user created to be validated to the controller but using the parent class type.  For example, PRNOrder is a concrete class that extends the abstract Order class.  Suppose a method that creates a PRNOrder object and passes it to the JSP :

```
Order order = new PRNOrder();
order.setOrderType(orderTypeService.findByName("PRN"));
```

I am currently able to use my controller method to validate the PRNOrder type with the following method signature :

```
public String savePRNOrder(@PathVariable String idPatient, @Valid @ModelAttribute("order") PRNOrder order, 
        BindingResult result, ModelMap model)
```

When i try changing the PRNOrder attribute to just Order to try and make it compatible with every subclass type i get the following exception :

```
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [mdhis_webclient.entity.Order]: Is it an abstract class?; nested exception is java.lang.InstantiationException
```

Spring is obviously trying to instantiate the object as an Order object but is there a way to have it treat the object as whatever type the object actually is and not have it try to instantiate an abstract class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i found something that works.  I created the following method in the controller :

```
@ModelAttribute("order")
public Order getOrderType(final HttpServletRequest request)
{
    String url = request.getRequestURI();
    String orderType = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("-") + 1, url.length());
    switch (orderType)
    {
        case "PRNOrder" : return new PRNOrder();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This allows me to use the Order class as the type since this method appears to tell Spring what kind of object to actually instantiate.  I can see potential issues with this since i have other methods that use an order attribute but this seems to work and i will expand it with the other types.

Comment: There is a fundamental flaw with this approach in that it will only work when ADDING an order.  If the user EDITS an order this will return a brand new object and obviously fail.  Still trying to find a way to solve this.

Comment: Actually it works fine for edits also!  Looks like Spring is smart enough to not just blindly re-instantiate an existing object.